# I've a build error with audioplayers package in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio-3.0

I've installed the audioplayers package for my flutter app and when I try to build the app it gives me this build error
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':audioplayers_android:extractDebugAnnotations'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':audioplayers_android:detachedConfiguration1'.
> Could not find intellij-core-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:30.3.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/30.3.0/intellij-core-30.3.0.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

and the application didn't start

I tried to delete the package and every thing went well
I tried `flutter clean` then `flutter build` and the problem didn't solved.
Help my plz :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

in android folder open build.gradle file and change the repositories with this :

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Comment: That didn't work still facing the same problem

Comment: There are two blocks of repositories in build.gradle, did you change both?

Comment: Yes I changed the project level and Allprojects level repos but nothing differ